# map hostname to directoy nginx and accessable through http

Tags: wordpress, nginx, centos

Im on NGINX

I have wordpress installed on: 
/home/kusanagi/wordpress1/DocumentRoot/
&
/home/kusanagi/wordpress2/DocumentRoot

My IP points to wordpress1/DocumentRoot, but id like http://IP/wordpress2 to point to /home/kusanagi/wordpress2/DocumentRoot.

So far ive tried adding to /etc/nginx/conf.d/_http.conf:

```
    location ~ /wordpress2 {
    root /home/kusanagi/wordpress2/DocumentRoot/;
    }
```

but i get a 502/404 or nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

point your ip by default to "/home/kusanagi" this path and restart your apache.

then you can access both url by using

http://ip/wordpress1

http://ip/wordpress2

Comment: im on nginx, not apache, where/how should i do this?

Comment: which os you are using for nginx

Comment: im running CentOS

Comment: i dont understand? How do i " point your ip by default to "/home/kusanagi"" ?

Comment: you can use "service nginx restart" also

Comment: etc/nginx/conf.d/_http.conf:  go to this fle and remove wordpress1/DocumentRoot  from path

Comment: ## default HTTP
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  default_server;

 
  location ~ / {
  root /home/kusanagi;
        }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

 
} ---- I get failed

Comment: I can help you if you give me server details on my email rajkumar.gaur.91@gmail.com